# Fedora 23 no longer bootable (GRUB: Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported.)

Tags: fedora, boot, grub2, dual-boot, uefi

I have a dual boot on my laptop with Windows 10 and Fedora 23. Both were installed in EFI mode. It's been working fine, but I had to set the boot order to prioritize BOOTX64.EFI for it to start launching GRUB. After two months of no issues, I suddenly see a page on boot saying:

> "GRUB: Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported."

It is then some kind of terminal prompt for GRUB. I can get back into Windows or live USBs by changing the boot order, but I have been unable to boot back into my fedora install since.

I've used a live Fedora USB to mount my Fedora system and try to reinstall grub2, but it says my `/boot` partition needs more space to install grub2. What can I do to fix this and boot back into my Fedora install?

Comment: You probably do not need to reinstall GRUB2. It is probable that your UEFI NVRAM BOOT0001, BOOT0002, etc. variables are missing or messed up.